# Use ContactsUI in app to create contacts on server in swift

Tags: ios, swift, contacts

i am working on an app where it has its own users/contacts that are retrieved from the server.

is there a way to make use of the contacts UI (i.e the view controllers to add/update users),so that i can use it instead of creating the same view controllers in my app.
Theses contacts cannot be added to the address book, but should be able to save to server.

Just wondering wether possible to reuse IOS functionalities.

Thanks in advance

Comment: No you cannot use the existing AddressBook view controllers to have custom data and save it on your own, you gotta build something on your own.

Comment: @satheeshwaran thanks man!..will start building up!